# Why currentPage does not do anything in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a paginator it does not display any error but when I click in the button 1 or 2 or 3 etc, it does not do anything so I wonder why not.

My component template code:

```
<v-pagination v-model="currentPage" 
                        :page-count="total"
                        :classes="bootstrapPaginationClasses"
                        :labels="paginationAnchorTexts"
                        ></v-pagination>
```

My script code:

```
export default {
    created() {
        this.getPosts();
    },
    methods: {
        getPosts() {
            fetch('/api/bank?page='+this.currentPage)
            .then(response => response.json() )
            .then(
                json => { 
                this.posts = json.data.data;
                this.total = json.data.last_page;
                this.currentPage = json.data.current_page;
            });
        }
    },
    components: { vPagination },
    data: function() {
        return {
            postsSelected: "",
            posts: [],
            currentPage: 1,
            total: 0,
            bootstrapPaginationClasses: {
                ul: 'pagination',
                li: 'page-item',
                liActive: 'active',
                liDisable: 'disabled',
                button: 'page-link'  
            },
            paginationAnchorTexts: {
                first: 'Primera',
                prev: '&laquo;',
                next: '&raquo;',
                last: 'Última'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if I have in the function getPosts(); the value this.currentPage it automaticly will send the current page, but when I click in 1 or 2 or 3 etc nothing happens, it just display 1 and nothing else, it does not display 1 several times just one time, so I think that I miss something which it fires something that it notifies that I am pushing the paginator button.

what do I miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do nothing when `currentPage` change. You can listen on `input` event and then call `getPosts`.

Example:

```html
<v-pagination
  v-model="page"
  @input='getPosts'>
</v-pagination>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1oxpyzm/)